# how to Stack columns in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a two columns and multiple rows in an excel sheet by using python i want to stack the data(similar way how we do in minitab)

This is how my data looks like

```
Adults-------------------------------->Children

Did Not Purchase------------------>Did Not Purchase

Did Not Purchase------------------>Purchased

Did Not Purchase------------------->Did Not Purchase

Did Not Purchase------------------->Purchased

Did Not Purchase------------------>Did Not Purchase

Did Not Purchase------------------->Did Not Purchase

Did Not Purchase-------------------->Did Not Purchase

Did Not Purchase------------------->Purchased

Did Not Purchase------------------->Did Not Purchase

Did Not Purchase------------------->Did Not Purchase

Did Not Purchase------------------->Did Not Purchase

Did Not Purchase-------------------->Did Not Purchase

Purchased-------------------------->Did Not Purchase

Purchased-------------------------->Did Not Purchase

Purchased-------------------------->Did Not Purchase

Did Not Purchase-------------------->Did Not Purchase

Did Not Purchase-------------------->Did Not Purchase

Did Not Purchase--------------------->Did Not Purchase

Did Not Purchase-------------------->Did Not Purchase
```

I have tried by using stack function this but what happened is data is storing in index values

```
stacked_df=two_prop_test.stack()
stacked_df
```

**Expected Result**

```
Person--------------                     Icecream   

Adults--------------                  Did Not Purchase  

Adults--------------                  Did Not Purchase  

Adults--------------                  Did Not Purchase  

Adults--------------                  Did Not Purchase  

Adults--------------                  Did Not Purchase  

Adults--------------                  Did Not Purchase  

Adults--------------                  Did Not Purchase  

Adults--------------                  Did Not Purchase  

Adults--------------                  Did Not Purchase  

Adults--------------                  Did Not Purchase  

Adults----------                  Did Not Purchase  

Adults----------                  Did Not Purchase  

Adults-----------                 Purchased 

Adults------------                Purchased 

Adults----------                  Purchased 

Adults-----------                 Did Not Purchase  

Adults-----------                 Did Not Purchase  

Adults-----------                 Did Not Purchase  

Children---------         Did Not Purchase  

Children---------         Purchased 

Children---------         Did Not Purchase  

Children---------         Purchased 

Children---------         Did Not Purchase  

Children---------         Did Not Purchase  

Children----------        Did Not Purchase  

Children---------         Purchased 

Children--------          Did Not Purchase  

Children---------        Did Not Purchase   

Children --------        Did Not Purchase   

Children--------         Did Not Purchase   

Children---------        Did Not Purchase   

Children--------         Did Not Purchase   

Children---------        Did Not Purchase   

Children---------        Did Not Purchase   

Children--------         Did Not Purchase   

Children--------         Did Not Purchase
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df_adult = df[['Adults']].copy()

df_child = df[['Children']].copy()

df_final = df_adult.append(df_child,ignore_index=True)
```